# How to pass information in dynamic built hyperlink?

Tags: html, sql, templates

*I have generated the following data using Template HTML*

**DATE     Bill Number     Bill Amount     Paid Amount     Bill Status**

2012-02-17  B0001          1200.00         1200.00          [Fully Paid][1]

2012-02-17  B0002          1000.00          300.00        [artially Paid][2]

2012-02-18  B0005          400.00             0.00          [Not Paid][3]

[1]: http://abc.cgi/BillNumber= B0001
  [2]: http://abc.cgi//BillNumber= B0002

Last column is a link.. which will take you to an cgi script. in cgi script i need to run a sql query.... where i need to pass the bill number in query.

My question is how to pass the respective bill number using Fully paid or partial paid or not paid hyperlink????

Please provide your suggestions.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You pass parameters to CGI scripts in the query part of a URL, after the “?” sign, separating parameters with an ampersand “&”, e.g.

http://www.example.com/yourscript.cgi?BillNumber=B00002&status=FullyPaid

The script then needs to parse the query part; but many programming languages used for CGI scripts have handy tools that do this for you.

Comment: BillNumber=B0002 is not fixed. It can be anything like BillNumber=B0001 BillNumber=B0002 BillNumber=B0003 or anything.. My question is how to append this thing in URL??

Comment: It depends on the software used to generate the HTML document how you generate URLs. It also depends on where you have the data to be put into the URLs.